# @Alternative-only CDI bean

Tags: cdi, java-ee-7

I am working on a project with two possible deployment environment, selected using @Alternative (or more specifically, @Stereotype) annotation. Let's call them envDefault and envAlt.
I am looking for a way to define a bean that has an @Alternative defined for envAlt, but has no @Default implementation for envDefault. I think this is viable, as the bean is not injected in any of common implementations, and actions that cause its creation (it @Observes specific event) will not happen in envDefault. Yet CDI fails to start the applicaiton, due to typical "Unsatisfied dependencies with qualifier @Default" exception at WeldStartService validation.

Is there a way to relax CDI validation for this specific bean to allow envDefault deployment without @Default implementation?

EDIT:
For reference, as it was already answered:

```
interface AltOnlyInterface {}

@Alternative
class AltOnlyBean implements AltOnlyInterface {}

//no default implementation of AltOnlyInterface

interface OtherInterface {}

//AltOnlyInterface is not use in default environment
class RegularOtherBean implements OtherInterface {}

@Alternative
class AltOtherBean implements OtherInterface {

    @Inject
    AltOnlyInterface altOnlyBean;
}
```

Comment: Can you post an example of how you've annotated these classes and the real error message disabled?  Did you enable either alternative in your beans.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no default implementation you should:

- create that implementation

  or
- make all injection points as Instance

If you want to have two environments and only in one has that bean. You need to annotate bean with `@Alternative` and enable it in one environtment. In the second environtment it will fail unless you have Instance at injection points.

Comment: OK, so it is not possible to relax CDI validation here. I guess using Instance is  cleaner than implementing some DummyDefault bean which will not be used anywhere. Thanks!